# Create a non-SegWit address in electrum wallet

Tags: transactions, address-generation

I am trying to get along the electrum wallet command line in ubuntu. However, my exchange only accepts withdraws to canonical non-SegWit addresses (i.e. it only generates with a "bc1" prefix). Is there a way to specifically specify such an option when typing `electrum createnewaddress`?

Comment: "bc1" addresses are segwit.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see any arguments in https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/b2be29b508deb310631cacfb51bb1561bce75ff9/electrum/commands.py#L795 to specify the address type similar to `address_type` used in Bitcoin Core's [getnewaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/getnewaddress/)
2. As sipa also mentioned in the comments, "bc1" prefix is used for segwit addresses
3. I think Electrum uses the default address type of wallet for creating new address which is decided while creating new wallet. So you can resolve this issue by creating a new wallet and select appropriate address type.

Answer (score 0):

open console and then type create(seed_type='standard')
then you open this with File->Open->THE NAME YOU CHOSE usually Default